# Speed up list comprehension, alternative?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, for-loop, list-comprehension

In my class i'm using a list comprehension which takes way too much time.

```
class Crack:

    def __init__(self, filename):
    
        self._mesh = pyfrd.Mesh(filename)
        self._filename = filename
     
        self._node_sets = self._mesh.node_sets[1:]  # list of front names

        self._calc_crack_length()
               
    @property
    def nodes(self):
        return self._mesh.nodes.values      # return coordinates of the nodes

    def _calc_crack_length(self):
        """
        this method calculates the crack length for every node
    
        Parameters
        ----------
    
    
        Returns
        -------
        """
        scalc_time = time.time()
    
        # nodes on all fronts as sets
        nodes_fronts = [np.array(self.nodes[self._front_start(i) - 1 : self._front_end(i)])
                    for i in range(len(self._node_sets))]
    
        print(f"t2: {time.time() - scalc_time}")
    ...
```

`self._node_sets` is a list of front names. Both `_front_start` and `_front_end` return a node number (first/last node of a front).

Are there better solutions than a list-comprehension?

Comment: If you have lots of data, it will take a long time. What is it that you want to do exactly?

Comment: in this list comprehension i want to create a list of arrays. Each array contains all the coordinates of the nodes on its front (of a crack).

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension is likely to allocate and re-allocate multiple times, as the list is built up. Since you know the length of the final list beforehand (`len(self._node_sets)`), this could be one area of improvement. So, you could try having a `numpy` array of `numpy` arrays in the place of the list of `numpy` arrays. You would be creating the `numpy` array of that known length, and then initializing the elements of that array with a similar loop as your list comprehension itself.

```
nodes_fronts_arr = np.empty(shape=(len(self._node_sets),), dtype=np.object)
for i in range(len(self._node_sets)):
    nodes_fronts_arr[i] = np.array(self.nodes[self._front_start(i) - 1 : self._front_end(i)])
```

**Note:**
Further improvement is possible if, in the above code, `nodes_front_arr` is created as a 2D array. But then, that would make sense only if each of the inner arrays has the same length. Whether that is so or not, is not mentioned in the problem detail at present.